# “Cut” part of an element (as the behavior of scroll)

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I am currently implementing a controller that changes the appearance of another HTML element, such that, when the event triggers, part of the element should be cut off (disappear).

The effect should be very similar to a regular scrollbar, showing in the window only a specific part of the element.

I was wondering what is the right approach to implement such a thing.

Run the snippet for image demonstration:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="481px" viewBox="-0.5 -0.5 481 281" content="&lt;mxfile host=&quot;app.diagrams.net&quot; modified=&quot;2020-08-24T20:16:04.706Z&quot; agent=&quot;5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.135 Safari/537.36&quot; etag=&quot;F-YfARe24URzr642LCEu&quot; version=&quot;13.6.5&quot; type=&quot;browser&quot;&gt;&lt;diagram id=&quot;9K3jEFCONYih4cx8FHUZ&quot; name=&quot;Page-1&quot;&gt;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&lt;/diagram&gt;&lt;/mxfile&gt;" onclick="(function(svg){var src=window.event.target||window.event.srcElement;while (src!=null&amp;&amp;src.nodeName.toLowerCase()!='a'){src=src.parentNode;}if(src==null){if(svg.wnd!=null&amp;&amp;!svg.wnd.closed){svg.wnd.focus();}else{var r=function(evt){if(evt.data=='ready'&amp;&amp;evt.source==svg.wnd){svg.wnd.postMessage(decodeURIComponent(svg.getAttribute('content')),'*');window.removeEventListener('message',r);}};window.addEventListener('message',r);svg.wnd=window.open('https://viewer.diagrams.net/?client=1&amp;edit=_blank');}}})(this);" style="cursor:pointer;max-width:100%;max-height:281px;"><defs/><g><rect x="0" y="60" width="200" height="160" fill="#dae8fc" stroke="#6c8ebf" pointer-events="all"/><path d="M 0 60 L 200 60 L 100 140 Z" fill="#f8cecc" stroke="#b85450" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"/><path d="M 0 220 L 200 220 L 100 140 Z" fill="#f8cecc" stroke="#b85450" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"/><g transform="translate(-0.5 -0.5)"><switch><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 198px; height: 1px; padding-top: 140px; margin-left: 1px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; ">Main Element</div></div></div></foreignObject><text x="100" y="144" fill="#000000" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="12px" text-anchor="middle">Main Element</text></switch></g><rect x="280" y="10" width="200" height="160" fill="#dae8fc" stroke="#6c8ebf" pointer-events="all"/><path d="M 280 10 L 480 10 L 380 90 Z" fill="#f8cecc" stroke="#b85450" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"/><path d="M 280 170 L 480 170 L 380 90 Z" fill="#f8cecc" stroke="#b85450" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"/><g transform="translate(-0.5 -0.5)"><switch><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 198px; height: 1px; padding-top: 90px; margin-left: 281px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; ">Main Element</div></div></div></foreignObject><text x="380" y="94" fill="#000000" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="12px" text-anchor="middle">Main Element</text></switch></g><rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="60" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="all"/><g transform="translate(-0.5 -0.5)"><switch><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 198px; height: 1px; padding-top: 30px; margin-left: 1px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; ">Another Element</div></div></div></foreignObject><text x="100" y="34" fill="#000000" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="12px" text-anchor="middle">Another Element</text></switch></g><rect x="0" y="220" width="200" height="60" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="all"/><g transform="translate(-0.5 -0.5)"><switch><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 198px; height: 1px; padding-top: 250px; margin-left: 1px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; ">Another Element</div></div></div></foreignObject><text x="100" y="254" fill="#000000" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="12px" text-anchor="middle">Another Element</text></switch></g><rect x="280" y="0" width="200" height="60" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="all"/><g transform="translate(-0.5 -0.5)"><switch><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 198px; height: 1px; padding-top: 30px; margin-left: 281px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; ">Another Element</div></div></div></foreignObject><text x="380" y="34" fill="#000000" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="12px" text-anchor="middle">Another Element</text></switch></g><rect x="280" y="220" width="200" height="60" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" pointer-events="all"/><g transform="translate(-0.5 -0.5)"><switch><foreignObject style="overflow: visible; text-align: left;" pointer-events="none" width="100%" height="100%" requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"><div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="display: flex; align-items: unsafe center; justify-content: unsafe center; width: 198px; height: 1px; padding-top: 250px; margin-left: 281px;"><div style="box-sizing: border-box; font-size: 0; text-align: center; "><div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 12px; font-family: Helvetica; color: #000000; line-height: 1.2; pointer-events: all; white-space: normal; word-wrap: normal; ">Another Element</div></div></div></foreignObject><text x="380" y="254" fill="#000000" font-family="Helvetica" font-size="12px" text-anchor="middle">Another Element</text></switch></g><path d="M 224 139.5 L 257.63 139.5" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="stroke"/><path d="M 262.88 139.5 L 255.88 143 L 257.63 139.5 L 255.88 136 Z" fill="#000000" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" pointer-events="all"/></g><switch><g requiredFeatures="http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/feature#Extensibility"/><a transform="translate(0,-5)" xlink:href="https://desk.draw.io/support/solutions/articles/16000042487" target="_blank"><text text-anchor="middle" font-size="10px" x="50%" y="100%">Viewer does not support full SVG 1.1</text></a></switch></svg>
```

Comment: window.scrollTo(0,yourelementoffsettop);

Comment: Yes :) this is what I was looking for (except it is on an element instead of window), along with `overflow: hidden` it works. Thanks :)